# no funciona <picture>

Tags: html

Tengo un sencillo ejemplo de `picture` que no logro hacer funcionar.

Lo curioso es que SIEMPRE toma la foto contenida en `<img src>` y nunca en ninguno de los dos `<srcset>` tenga el tamaño que tenga la página. Incluso el IDE (visual studio code) no me asiste ni sugiere imágenes del directorio cuando estoy escribiendo el `<srcset>` lo que me da la pauta de que ni siquiera lo está reconociendo (a diferencia de cuando escribo el `<img src>` que sí lo hace).  ¿Que podrá ser?

```html
<div style="background-color: black;">
 <picture>
   <source srcset="images/foto retocada.png" media="(min-width: 401px)" >
   <source srcset="gubernamental.jpg" media="(max-width: 400px)">
   <img src="gubernamental.jpg" alt="Flowers" >
 </picture>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado. era simplemente el espacio del nombre de la imagen en  `<source srcset="images/foto retocada.png" media="(min-width: 401px)" >`

lo cambié tanto en el directorio como en el código por `images/foto-retocada.png`

Comment: Nunca tengas espacios en las de tus archivos y/o carpetas. Eso lo carga el diablo como se suele decir :)